# Event handler stack

Tags: events, haskell

I want to implement a stack of objects which can exchange in events. Upon receiving an event form either above or below, an object could emit other events to ether side or change state (but keep its place in the stack).

At the moment I have this working. I have a type `Animation a b` which is a container for event handler that receives (from above) events of type `a` and emits (up) events of type `b` and I have a function `handle :: Handler -> Animation g h -> Animation e f` to stack them.

The actual type of `Handler` is

```
Animation g h -> (Either e h) -> 
    WriterT [Either g f] IO (Either (Animation e f) (Animation g h))
```

Here `(Either e h)` is an event coming from above or below, `[Either g f]` is events emitted down or up and `Either (Animation e f) (Animation g h)` is the result either as an independent object or one that uses the same handler. And I am not happy.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Your `Animation` type sounds similar to what `pipes` or `conduit` libraries offer

Comment: @cdk, I'm not well familiar with those, but it seems that both are cantered on data transformations whereas for me, the most important requirement is for each `Animation` to be able to replace itself.

Answer (score 6):

This is exactly what the `Proxy` type from `pipes` does.  Diagramatically, it looks a bit like this:

```
 Upstream | Downstream
     +---------+
     |         |
 a' <==       <== b'
     |         |
 a  ==>       ==> b
     |    |    |
     +----|----+
          v
          r
```

It has two interfaces: an upstream interface and a downstream interface.  It sends and receives information on both interfaces.  This is analogous to a layer in your stack where "upstream" might be the stack frame above it "downstream" might be the stack frame below it.

To communicate to the upstream interface, you use `request`, which has this type:

```
request :: Monad m => a' -> Proxy a' a b' b m a
```

In other words, `request` sends a value of type `a'` upstream and waits for a response of type `a`.

The dual of `request` is `respond`, which communicates on the downstream interface:

```
respond :: Monad m => b -> Proxy a' a b' b m b'
```

`respond` sends a value of type `b` downstream and waits for a response of type `b'`.

A `Proxy` can be in one of three states.  It can either be:

- Waiting for a response from upstream

Its type would indicates that it's waiting for an `a`:

```
waitingUp :: a -> Proxy a' a b' b m r
```

- Waiting for a response from downstream:

Its type would indicate that it's waiting for a `b'`:

```
waitingDn :: b' -> Proxy a' a b' b m r
```

- Currently active, and not waiting for anything:

Its type would indicate that it's not waiting for any value:

```
notWaiting :: Proxy a' a b' b m r
```

There are four ways you can connect these three states:

- Connect a `Proxy` waiting on downstream to an active `Proxy`, which generates a new active `Proxy`.

This is what the `(+>>)` operator does:

```
(+>>)
    :: Monad m
    => (b' -> Proxy a' a b' b m r)  -- Waiting on downstream
    ->        Proxy b' b c' c m r   -- Active
    ->        Proxy a' a c' c m r   -- Active
```

- Connect an active `Proxy` to a `Proxy` waiting on upstream, which generates a new active `Proxy`.

This is what the `(>>~)` operator does:

```
(>>~)
    :: Monad m
    =>       Proxy a' a b' b m r   -- Active
    -> (b -> Proxy b' b c' c m r)  -- Waiting on upstream
    ->       Proxy a' a c' c m r   -- Active
```

- Connect two `Proxy`s that are both waiting on upstream, to generate a new `Proxy` waiting on upstream.

This is what the `(>~>)` operator does:

```
(>~>)
    :: Monad m
    => (a -> Proxy a' a b' b m r)  -- Waiting on upstream
    -> (b -> Proxy b' b c' c m r)  -- Waiting on upstream
    -> (a -> Proxy a' a c' c m r)  -- Waiting on upstream
```

- Connect two `Proxy`s that are both waiting on downstream, to generate a new `Proxy` waiting on downstream.

This is what the `(>+>)` operator does:

```
(>+>)
    :: Monad m
    => (b' -> Proxy a' a b' b m r)  -- Waiting on downstream
    -> (c' -> Proxy b' b c' c m r)  -- Waiting on downstream
    -> (c' -> Proxy a' a c' c m r)  -- Waiting on downstream
```

Here's an example of three stack frames implemented and connected this way.  I will use the convention that the stack starts from upstream, although the implementation is totally symmetric and you can use the opposite convention if you prefer:

```
import Pipes.Core
import Pipes

--                +-+-- Closed upstream interface
--                | |
--                v v
up :: () -> Proxy X () String Int IO ()
up () = do
    str1 <- respond 4
    lift (putStrLn str1)
    str2 <- respond 5
    lift (putStrLn str2)

middle :: Int -> Proxy String Int Double Char IO ()
middle int = do
    lift (print int)
    double <- respond (head (show int))
    lift (print double)
    int' <- request (show double)
    middle int'

--  Closed downstream interface --+-+
--                                | |
--                                v  v
down :: Char -> Proxy Double Char () X IO ()
down char1 = do
    lift (print char1)
    char2 <- request (1.0)
    lift (print char2)
    char3 <- request (2.0)
    lift (print char3)

--                   +-+--+--+-- Everything closed
--                   | |  |  |
--                   v v  v  v
total :: () -> Proxy X () () X IO ()
total = up >~> middle >~> down

main :: IO ()
main = runEffect $ total ()
```

This produces the following output:

```
>>> main
4
'4'
1.0
1.0
5
'5'
2.0
2.0
```

Try to trace the execution path by hand, starting from the `up` `Proxy`.  Every time that `up` `respond`s with a value, that hands off control to `middle`, and every time `middle` `respond` with a value that hands off control to `down`.  Vice versa, every time `down` `request`s a value, that hands off control to `middle`, and every time `middle` `request`s a value that hands off control to `up`.  If any pipe in the chain terminates then the whole chain terminates.

Edit: To answer your question, yes, you can change the behavior based on the result.  Just write `middle` like this:

```
middle :: Int -> Proxy String Int Double Char IO ()
middle int = do
    lift (print int)
    double <- respond (head (show int))
    case double of
        0.0 -> foo
        _   -> bar
```

... where `foo` and `bar` are both `Proxy`s with the same inputs and outputs as `middle`:

```
foo :: Proxy String Int Double Char IO ()

bar :: Proxy String Int Double Char IO ()
```

when you sequence two `Proxy`s, the second `Proxy` begins where the first `Proxy` ends.  You're not limited to sequencing primitive commands like `request` and `respond`.  You can call any `Proxy` of an arbitrary number of steps as a subroutine within a larger `Proxy` as long as it shares the same upstream and downstream interface.

Comment: Is it possible to write `middle` in such way, that whenever it gets a certain response from upstream, it replaces itself with another `Proxy`, `foo` of the same type, so that the whole effect would be equivalent to `up >~> foo >~> down`? Could it turn into just `up >~> foo`? In other words, the example is great for message passing, but what about state?

Comment: Yes.  I updated my answer with the details of how to do that.  The short answer is: just call `foo` directly and it will just work.